# Assigning the value of a variable defined in a function to a variable in a separate function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

```
def initColors():
   BLACK = (0,0,0)  
   RED = (255,0,0)
   BLUE = (0,0,255)
   LIGHTGRAY = (128,128,128)
   DARKGRAY = (64,64,64)
   WHITE = (255,255,255)
initColors()
def initOtherVars():
   nhover = WHITE
   hover = RED
   mselected = BLACK
   selected = RED
initOtherVars()
```

I want it to set the value of *nhover* to the value of *WHITE*, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\jarr3\Desktop\Python\Battlr\battlrSelectionScreen1.py", line 30, in <module>
initOtherVars()
   File "C:\Users\jarr3\Desktop\Python\Battlr\battlrSelectionScreen1.py", line 27, in initOtherVars
      nhover = WHITE
NameError: name 'WHITE' is not defined
```

It seems that a variable cannot be assigned to the value of a variable that is defined in a function in a function, even if the first function is called before the second one is even defined. Why is this? And is there a different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. (Besides just not using functions, I would like to keep using functions.) Thanks.

Comment: read:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules. Python has scopes, variables are only valid inside the scope.

Comment: Why bother with two `init*` methods? Just have one.

Comment: Two methods for organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has scopes. Variables are only known inside scopes. You can define variables global to force them to be available in a global scope, but that clutters it and it is bad practice.

More on that, see [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules).

You can make yours global:

```
def initColors():
    # declare them global
    global BLACK,RED,BLUE,LIGHTGRAY,DARKGRAY,WHITE
    BLACK = (0,0,0)  
    RED = (255,0,0)
    BLUE = (0,0,255)
    LIGHTGRAY = (128,128,128)
    DARKGRAY = (64,64,64)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)

initColors()

def initOtherVars():
    # need to be global as well, else invalid outside this scope 
    global nhover,hover,mselected,selected
    nhover = WHITE
    hover = RED
    mselected = BLACK
    selected = RED

initOtherVars()
```

Going this way you first have to put the colors into the global space and then also your other variables.

---

You could create a class that holds your colors as class-variables, which makes it accessable over `Classname.Varname`:

```
class MyColors:
   BLACK = (0,0,0)  
   RED = (255,0,0)
   BLUE = (0,0,255)
   LIGHTGRAY = (128,128,128)
   DARKGRAY = (64,64,64)
   WHITE = (255,255,255)

def initOtherVarsByClass():
    # these need still to be made global
    global Cnhover,Chover,Cmselected,Cselected
    Cnhover = MyColors.WHITE
    Chover = MyColors.RED
    Cmselected = MyColors.BLACK
    Cselected = MyColors.RED

initOtherVarsByClass()
```

But you still need to make your other variables `global` to have access to those you defined in your function. I think it would be easier to make a class as "holder" and create your `mselected` etc. in it to be accessed over the class.

```
class LinkColors():
    nhover = MyColors.WHITE
    hover = MyColors.RED
    mselected = MyColors.BLACK
    selected = MyColors.RED
```

You could as well create functions that simply return your color:

```
def GetSelected(): 
    return MyColors.RED
```

---

Instead of cluttering the global space you get more classes.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `initcolors()` is different to to scope of `initOtherVars()`. You could create one function which includes all your variables.

Or, if you wish to have two separate objects, you can consider object-oriented programming and feed an instance of one class to another. For example:

```
class initColors():
    def __init__(self):
        self.BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        self.RED = (255, 0, 0)
        self.WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

MyColors = initColors()

class initOtherVars(initColors):
    def __init__(self, color_class):
        self.nhover = color_class.WHITE
        self.hover = color_class.RED
        self.mselected = color_class.BLACK
        self.selected = color_class.RED

MyOtherVars = initOtherVars(MyColors)

print(MyOtherVars.nhover)  # (255, 255, 255)
```